# Using JSONP for cross domain request

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add some content from another website to my own site. I have the folowing script in head:

```
<script>
var res = $.ajax({
async: true,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: 'http://www.crestinortodox.ro/embed/agendacrestinului/listacalendar/mycss/callback/',
success: function(r) {
$("#cocalendar").html(r.content_html);
}
});
</script>
```

My html code is:

```
<div id="cocalendar" class="co">&nbsp;</div>
```

I tried changing to https in the code, but it still doesn't show on my website.

What could be the issue here? I'm a newbie, maybe it's something obvious?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Possibly it is a timing issue to do with the order of your HTML and JS.

Comment: Well you are putting a script in the head that manipulates the DOM. You need to wait for document.ready or window.onload.

Comment: How would I do that? Can you expand on your answer, please?

Comment: This didn't work for me, I added the code to it:


$(window).on('load', function() {
    // your code here
});